# How to write the enter keys in a web page, that were saved in Database via textarea

Tags: asp.net, replace, sql-server-ce

I have tried alot of search suggestions to make it work. But I am not able to find why its not working. On another forum, I asked for help and they said: **Use string.replace()** I am using ASP.NET Web Pages and the SqlCe as a database.

What I have tried is this:

```
<div><h3>About Me: </h3>
   @{ 
      var About = row.About;
      var aboutReplaced = About.Replace('\n', '<br />');
   }
   @aboutReplaced
</div>
```

And please note that `row.About` is being achieved as a result of a `foreach (var row in result)` loop.

The issue that I am facing is something like this:

1. When I use the code as: `About.Replace('\n', '<br />');` it gives an error saying, `Too many characters in character literal`.
2. When I use the code as: `About.Replace("\n", "<br />");` It gives me an output, with `<br />` written inside the page. I know it creates a string of it.

So what should I do?

Both methods are not working. And I have seen one other method here too, and that's to use some code in PHP, I am working with ASP.NET so that's not gonna work! What I get now is:

`Hi <br />My name is afzaal! I am 18 years old. <br /> <br />Cheers!` this is what I get as an output. Insteand of this I want to get this like as follows:

```
Hi <br />My name is afzaal! I am 18 years old. And I have done all the coding work for this website! <br /> <br />Cheers!
```

I hope you can understand my description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor HTML encodes strings by default. You can use the `@Html.Raw` helper to write your string without HTML encoding.

Take care to encode the rest of the string though:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(row.About).Replace("\n", "<br />"))
```

Comment: Good. Feel free to accept the answer if it was the solution to your problem.